# Why ConversationReference service url is different than localhost?

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, bots

I'm using the Microsoft Bot Framework V4.
When i use the code following bellow

```
    public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext context, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {

        var conversationReference = context.Activity.GetConversationReference();
        System.Console.Write(conversationReference.ServiceUrl);

    }
```

The value printed is http://localhost:62304 but the app is running on this address http://localhost:4353/api/messages

Is there a difference between this addresses?
Is there a way they have the same value?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the emulator. The localhost:62304 is the emulated direct line service. You don't want them to be the same value. Your bots endpoint, and the directline service are two different things, and neither will be localhost (obviously) once your bot is published and connected to channels.

Is there an problem that this is causing?

Comment: No, It is not a problem. But I am developing a auth middleware redirect to my front end to user consent the bot to use his/her login. That front is developed using Vue after user consent the Vue call the my auth controller that's is responsible to get the user's ok then send to the bot the user's token authentication. To do that I'm serializing the ConversationReferance and passing through the stack. And finnaly my problem is the Vue App need to know where is the controller.

Comment: Okay. You _can_ use a custom oauth provider with the typical flow. You might not need to implement in the middleware. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication